# How to specify the bind address for a JBoss EAP server?

Tags: eclipse, jboss

I configured Jboss EAP-6.4.0 to run my project from eclipse,and its working fine when trying with `loalhost` but when i am trying with machine ip(`http://ip:8080`) it is not responding.

I tried to add `-c default -b 0.0.0.0` inside eclipse `Launch Configuration->Arguments` section but then i am getting

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBAS014805: Could not get main file:
>   default. Specified files must be relative to the configuration dir:
>   C:\Users\subodhc\EAP-6.4.0\standalone\configuration   at
>   org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationFile.determineMainFile(ConfigurationFile.java:168)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationFile.(ConfigurationFile.java:95)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.server.ServerEnvironment.(ServerEnvironment.java:393)
>     at org.jboss.as.server.Main.determineEnvironment(Main.java:265)     at
>   org.jboss.as.server.Main.main(Main.java:93)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   org.jboss.modules.Module.run(Module.java:312)     at
>   org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:473)

Can someone please let me know how to bind ipaddress  ?

Answer (score 2):

In xml file specify IP address at `jboss.bind.address.management` and `jboss.bind.address`. Or specify `JAVA_OPTION` in `standalone.conf/standalone.conf.bat`.

From eclipse side, click on server-> open and change host name from localhost to 0.0.0.0.

Comment: Thanks for your reply

Comment: Is this anyway to use from eclipse as well rather than changing config files

Comment: click on server-> open and change host name from localhost to 0.0.0.0.

Comment: No need to change the other place or configuration file?

Comment: Some places we have to change the config file some places through direct from editor

Comment: Which XML file?

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended not to use the configuration to hardcode the bind address of the application server. You should provide System Properties to the standalone.sh startup file, for example:

```
./standalone.sh -b=hostname -bmanagement=hostname
```

You can also bind the application server to all IP Addresses using 0.0.0.0 although that exposes, in production systems, to security threats.

Source: http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-configuration/how-to-bind-wildfly-to-an-ip-address